# Converting Base 64 string in SOAP response to PDF using XSLT

Tags: pdf, base64, xslt-2.0

My requirement is to get a PDF file from one system and send it across to another.
By making a webservice call I have been able to get the BASE64 encoding of the PDF file in the SOAP response.

Now I need to convert this BASE64 string back to PDF and dump the PDF onto the other system.
Am stuck at the point of converting the BASE64 string in the SOAP response to PDF. I understand that it is something achievable in XSLT. I have been researching but unfortunately didn't get anything concrete so far.

Can somebody throw some light on how to handle this in XSLT? A sample code snippet will be very helpful. If there is a better approach to this situation please let me know.

Thanks
Abhijit

Comment: I don't see why XSLT would help, other than extracting maybe the base64 encoded string. But to take it and decode it back to the bytes making up the PDF you need a library like http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html and then simply write the bytes to a file, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: have a look at http://expath.org/modules/binary/, it grew out of a discussion we had when we wanted to introduce support for arbitrary data and non-XML characters in XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

During discussions within the XSL WG, we came up with a requirement that did not fit into the XSLT specification at the time, but we did take it into an [EXPath](http://expath.org) specification: [Binary Module 1.0](http://expath.org/spec/binary).

The native data for the binary module is `xs:base64Binary`. If you know your Base-64 string is a proper Base 64 string and does not require any further processing, except that it must be written as binary PDF, you can do the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="file:write-binary($file, $value)" />
```

The output of the function is defined as the empty sequence, so writing does not yield any effects in your current output stream. You can find more info on the [`file:Write-binary` function in the spec](http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.write-binary).

Currently, I know that [Saxon](http://saxonica.com) is [going to implement it](http://expath.org/modules/binary/implems) (or already has), and that we for [Exselt](http://exselt.net) are planning on implementing it soon after initial release.

Note:

> *"I understand that it is something achievable in XSLT."*

No, not out-of-the-box. But XSLT can convert XML or other input to XSL-FO (or other intermediate output) which can be rendered into PDF, which is a very common XSLT programming use-case.

Yet, XSLT is very extensible, and you can either write your own extension functions, or use extension functions from well-known libraries, like in this case, from the Binary Module.